# Get height of a view - Variable needs to be declared final

Tags: java, android, view, height

I want to get the height of a view using the TreeObserver method:

```
        int v1_h;
        v1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(newViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //now we can retrieve the width and height

                v1_h = v1.getHeight();


                if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    v1.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                else
                    v1.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });

//Do something with v1_h later on
```

I want to store the height in a variable and use later on.  Problem is that it needs to declared final to be accessed from within inner class.  So I make it final, but now it says it can't be assigned.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Declare v1_h in a top level scope you call addOnGlobalLayoutListener method

Comment: I don't understand.  I tried putting v1_h above onGlobalLayout() as like a global variable but then it couldn't be found later down below when I'm outside of the tree observer code.  Could you please explain?

Comment: @user1197993 Reason for unaccepting the answer I provided?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to declare the variable as a class member instead of a variable declared on the stack.  If you make v1_h final, you won't really be able to use it the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `v1_h` and the inner class you created "`new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()...`" are in the same scope, If you want to change the value of `v1_h` you should move the declaration to an upper level of scope, I don't know how exactly your code goes but I make an example to understand what I'm talking about:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//The scope you should declare your variable in, No need to declare as a final
//Here is an upper level scope than inner class's!
int v1_h;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    //1.The scope you declared your variable in 
    //2.Where the inner class is
        v1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)
    //1 && 2 => They were in the same scope in your code
    ...
    }
}
```

Hope it help...

Comment: Yeah I tried making it a global variable, but it didn't update the value when it came time to getting the height.  For some reason the value stored in v1_h was always 0 even though getHeight() was returning the correct values.

Comment: If you don't get compile time error anymore it's a different issue, Ask another question please.